# Detect screen shutdown in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, events, screen, shutdown

I'm building an application using vb.net that should record some specific user actions, one of these actions is the screen shutdown, is there a way to do that? Maybe a system event or something that i can check periodically to know if the screen is active or not.

I've already found some code to check if the screensaver is running but i want to know if there's a way to detect if the screen is phisically turned off.